# Crossing Hungarian-Serbian border with Dutch driving licence

Tags: customs-and-immigration, driving, borders, serbia

I will be hiring a car in Hungary, then cross the border to Serbia. Officially you don't need an international driving licence because Serbia is supposed to accept Dutch driving licences.

However, we heard that sometimes the police at the border do make a fuss and you end up paying for some rules they make up.

How often does this happen, how corrupt are officials there even now?

**Update:** I'm back, and it turned out not buying one was the right choice. At the border crossing they only checked passports, and going from Serbia to Hungary they checked the trunk (against human trafficking, all luggage could stay closed).

Comment: An International Driving Permit  (international rijbewijs) is not expensive, why not visit the ANWB shop and walk out with one?

Comment: @Willeke Because it's not needed. EU licences use a common Format and the Serbs ought to be well familiar with it owing to ist EU neighbours. And like I said, chances that you'll be asked for a licence at the border are fairly slim

Comment: @Crazydre the context of the question is possible corruption leading to a demand for a bribe. In that context "because it's not needed" isn't a particularly compelling argument.

Comment: During many crossings in 2017, nobody ever cared about the car. Passport and reason for trip is all that matters.

Comment: @phoog, the question was how likely it is that they demand bribes. My knowledge is based on what friends say that "people they know have experienced in the past". Getting an international driving permit is a solution, but if it's not necessary it's nothing more than throwing money in the sink :)

Comment: Indeed, in that context of the question "how likely..." it's even harder to argue that the permit is "not needed" unless you can show that the probability of being asked for a bribe is unaffected by possession of a permit, or at least that the magnitude of the impact on the probability is too small to outweigh the cost of obtaining the permit.  I've never been to Serbia, but I have driven into and out of three other former Yugoslav republics and nobody ever checked my driver's license, just the documents for the car.

Comment: You could add your update as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slight correction:

> However, we heard that sometimes the police at the border **used to** make a fuss and you end up paying for some rules they make up.

Nowadays, the Serbs are really the most lax and nonchalant border officers I've ever dealt with. Chances are they won't even ask for car-related papers for a Hungarian-plated car, but simply check your passport or *identiteitskaart* and send you on your way.

If you use a passport, your main concern should be getting an entry stamp, which they're often too lazy to do. An exit stamp isn't needed, however.

Comment: I've had issues with Croatian immigration due to a missing Serbian exit stamp, so I would not be so sure about the correctness of your last paragraph. The missing exit stamp was allegedly proof that I had left Serbia and entered Croatia illegaly without using an official border crossing.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I researched the official law the other day, and Serbia has the weirdest stamping policy I've ever heard of: Serbian passports are to be stamped on exit but not entry, and foreign passports on entry but not exit

Comment: Didn't get an entry stamp when crossing the border. Did get one while getting my visa.

Comment: @Geliormth What visa? And if you didn't get an entry stamp, I can only hope you won't be stopped and scrutinised by the police in the country or on exit

Comment: @Crazydre, stayed in Serbia for 2 weeks, doing volunteering work. So we got a visa, and a stamp in our passports while getting the visa. Leaving the country was no problem ;)